# How can I read pixel values from the framebuffer on the raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, framebuffer

Can someone tell me how to read pixel values from the framebuffer on the raspberry pi? As far as I understand, the framebuffer keeps the information about whats currently on the screen, right? So my idea was to play a RTSP stream using omxPlayer and then read the framebuffer in order to control some LEDs for an Ambilight. Is that possible? How would I achieve this? Could you think of a better solution in order to get pixel information from something played by omxPlayer?

Comment: I know that's possible with [openFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/setup/raspberrypi/) and it's [ofxOMXPlayer](https://github.com/jvcleave/ofxOMXPlayer) addon which allows you to also [read pixels](https://github.com/jvcleave/ofxOMXPlayer/blob/master/src/ofxOMXPlayer.h#L63). If you're not planning to use c++/openFrameworks, you can still check out the source and see how the gl texture is retrieved from the buffer and individual pixels can be accessed

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza So far I have tried opencv but its way too slow. I expected the same issue with openFrameworks (without testing it). I just tried to grab a frame from omxPlayer by using fbgrab, but the screenshot does not contain the omxPlayer output...

Comment: Are you trying to read pixels from the pi camera module ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza No I have an prototype that can decode a HDMI Input and stream it via RTSP. I'd like to play that stream using omxPlayer and process the frames in order to control LEDs (Ambilight) on my raspberry pi. The main problem is that I need a player that runs hardware accelerated (GPU) because the CPU of the raspberry pi is very slow.

Comment: I guess I have to check the boblight source code, because they did what I was looking for